# How to remove image upload from ckeditor?

Tags: java, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and i don't want to add image through ckeditor that's why i would like to remove image upload functionality from ckeditor[image]

Now i face another problem ,after removing that link i still can copy paste images in firfox ,rest of browser 
doesn't work like this, i want to remove copy paste functionality in firefox too.please help

Comment: In your edit "rest of browser" means other browsers like IE and Chrome?I don't think you can remove copy paste cause it's a default funtionality in Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove it from CKEditor toolbar in Config.js or wherever you are using that toolbar.Go to this link and Read the documentation and you will understand the customization of the toolbar.http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar